# How to fix " EnumDropDownListFor on new account creation "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have an `EnumDropDownListFor` control on my register page that lets you choose from two options. I have tried registering two accounts with both options but both accounts always default to the first option.

This always worked during testing when running the code in debug, however now the code is in build it no longer works even though no code has been altered.

### Enum for dropdown

```
public enum RaceName 
{ 
    Terran, 
    AsphaMiner 
}
```

### Register.cshtml

```
// rest of file

<div class="form-group">                                        
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RaceName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-6">                                   
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.RaceName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div></div>

// more of file below too
```

### AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var user = new ApplicationUser
      {
               UserName = model.UserName,
               Email = model.Email
               RaceName = model.RaceName,
   // rest of controller
```

### IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public RaceName RaceName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Race PlayerRace { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        PlayerRace = new Race(this);
    }
    // rest of default code
```

### Race.cs

```
public virtual ApplicationUser RaceOwner { get; set; }
public Race(ApplicationUser user)
{
    RaceOwner = user;
}
// other properties with [NotMapped] attribute so
// static values are not saved to sql db
```

### RegisterViewModel.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} 
    characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation 
    password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public RaceName RaceName { get; set; }        
}
```

So the user creates an account, inputs their username email password etc, then they choose from a `DropDownList` 1 of 2 options but it always selects the first option and I have not changed anything between going from debug to build versions.

If I select `AsphaMiner`, it sets it to `Terran`; and if I select `Terran` it sets it to `Terran`.

Can anyone recommend anything?

Comment: It seems the enum value is not getting passed to action.  Hence by default it is taking the 0 value for the enum.   How are you setting RaceName ?  Do you have any javascript or something to set it ?

Comment: the racename is being passed with my registerviewmodel

Comment: i have updated my post with the viewmodel.

Comment: But how are you setting the RaceName ?  Can you check in fiddler if this value is being sent to action through http message ? Also i would suggest to use different name for property.  Enum name and property name is same currently.

Comment: if i change the poperty name from RaceName it completely breaks it.
the RaceName is being set from the enumdropdown in the registerviewmodel
this is passed from view to controller and set in the accountcontroller RaceName = model.RaceName